# How to randomly select column that does not contain a specific value in Excel or SPSS

Tags: excel, vba, spss

Would anyone know the Excel formula, VBA, or SPSS syntax to do the following:

Create a new variable/column in a dataset or spreadsheet which is populated by the column number (or column title) of a randomly selected column (from a range of 1-42 columns), provided the value in that column for a given row does not contain 99.

In Excel I can do the first step and create random numbers and match these to columns, but I don't know how (or if possible) to 're-roll' a new random number if the initial matched column contains the value 99.

My formula for generating a random number between 1 and 42 to identify a column:
AQ=RANDBETWEEN(1,3)

For a row in Excel using 9-row dummy data: =HLOOKUP(AQ,$A$1:$AP$9,2,FALSE)

Comment: Consider sharing your code and what you've tried so far in more details. You will be more likely to get useful help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] to learn what we'll do to help you. TL;DR: this isn't a code writing service so you'll have to provide your best shot at it and indicate where you're stuck, then someone will help you fix that specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can re-roll... for the given row, I chose `10` but you can change this however you need

EDIT - now looping thru `givenRow`:

```
Sub test()

    Dim randCol As Integer
    Dim givenRow As Long
    Dim saveCol As Integer: saveCol = 44 ' where to store results

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("your sheet name")
        For givenRow = 1 To 100
            Do While True
                ' get column between 1 and 42
                randCol = Int(42 * Rnd + 1)
                ' if not 99 exit
                If .Cells(givenRow, randCol).Value <> 99 Then Exit Do
            Loop
            ' store results in saveCol for givenRow
            .Cells(givenRow, saveCol).Value = randCol
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly! I don't suppose you know of a quick way to create a column which saves the returned results for givenRows 1-100?

Comment: @P_Jefferies editted the answer by adding a `For` loop to go thru rows 1-100 and store results in column 44.... you can change that column number tho

Comment: @P_Jefferies Np, just be careful as it could loop forever if all values are 99 for a row

Answer (score 0):

Heres how you could go about it in SPSS using Python:

```
begin program. 
import spss, spssaux
import random

# get variable list
vars = spssaux.VariableDict().expand(spss.GetVariableName(0) + " to " + spss.GetVariableName(spss.GetVariableCount()-1))

proceed = True
breakcount = 0

while proceed:
# generate random integer between 0 and variable count -1, get random variable's             
# name and index-position in dataset
    rng = random. randint(0,spss.GetVariableCount() - 1)
    ranvar = spss.GetVariableName(rng)
    ind = int(vars.index(ranvar))

# read data from random variable, if value 99 is stored in the variable, go back to the top. if not, compute variable 
# random_column = column number (index +1 NOT index) 
    randat = spss.Cursor([ind])
    d = randat.fetchall()
    randat.close()  
    data = [str(x).strip('(),') for x in d]
    breakcount += 1
    if "99.0" not in data:
        spss.Submit("compute random_column = %s." %(ind + 1))
        proceed = False
    elif breakcount == 42:
        break

end program.
```

it iterates through random variables until it finds one without the value 99 in it, then computes the new variable containing the comlumn number.

Edit: Added a break condition so that it doesnt loop infinitely just in case every variable contains a 99

Comment: thanks for this. I'm wrestling with SPSS to get the Essentials for Python to work. It's telling me it's not installed, but it is...